# Where is the moov atom in silverlight?

Tags: vlc-media-player, video-streaming, silverlight

I monitored my network traffic to find the stream URL for silverlight video. When I opened that URL with VLC it didn't find moov atom and wasn't able to stream.

Could moov atom be in silverlight .XAP file? If it is, is there any easy way to "append" moov atom to URL stream?

-- More questions:

If the moov atom is at the end of the stream the stream length has to be in .XAP file? To first get the moov atom silverlight app offsets to end of the stream and optains the moov atom , it does not get the moov atom inside the .XAP file?

Comment: If you have another question please post it as a **new** question, don't tag it onto this one. It wont get answered.

Answer (score 1):

[Understanding the MPEG-4 movie atom](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/video/articles/mp4_movie_atom.html):

"The optimal location of the moov atom depends on the selected delivery method."

---

[Why is my progressive H.264 video not playing until the entire file is downloaded.](http://www.scottgmorgan.com/blog/index.php/2008/01/23/why-is-my-progressive-h264-video-not-playing-until-the-entire-file-is-downloaded/)

“One important thing about playing an H.264 video file as progressive download is that the moov atom needs to be located at the beginning of the file, or else the entire file will have to be downloaded before it begins playing. … Unfortunately tools … place this information at the end of the file" … "Scouring the web I did find **[a utility that moves the moov atom to the start of the file](http://renaun.com/blog/code/qtindexswapper/)**. Renaun Erickson ported a C app to AIR that moves the moov atom and resaves the file"

Comment: You sure that Silverlight video uses h.264?

Comment: @slhck: From that article: "Silverlight supported H.264 video and everyone was raving about it."

Comment: Ah, I just [found out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080(VS.95).aspx) that Silverlight in fact is able to stream h.264 Annex B.